# how to get the day from the date in sql and C#?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

Does anyone know how to get the day part from a datetime? For example, I have a datetime 2013-11-30 11:53:02.360. I just need the 30 from the datetime. How do I get it using sql and C#?

Update: Maybe I didn't explain it right. Here is the scenario:
We have a record in our table which has start date and end date, for example:
2013-10-03 11:53:02.360
2013-10-08 14:36:01.090

In my web page I have an event that only occurs if the current day is between 3-8, I don't care about the year and month. So if the current date is 2014-01-05, the event will occur.

Now I question is, if I have 2013-09-30 ... as start date in the table, how do I check to make sure the event will still occur? Basically I think I need to check current date is fall into the same rage of the dates defined in the table.

Comment: What have you tried?  If you have a DateTime instance `d`, it should be as simple as `d.Day`.  How exactly is sql playing into this?

Comment: you surely kidding?? really

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.Parse("2013-11-30 11:53:02.360").Day
```

Answer (score 2):

In T-SQL (assuming you're talking about **SQL Server** when you say **SQL**):

```
 SELECT DAY(GETDATE())
```

In C#:

```
int day = DateTime.Today.Day;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your date Type is `DateTime`  and contains `2013-11-30 11:53:02.360`

Try This:

```
String Day=dt.ToString("dd"); //it contains Day-> 03
```

**( or )**

if your date Type is String and contains `2013-11-30 11:53:02.360`

Try This:

```
String strDate = "2013-11-03 11:53:02.360";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",   
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

String Day=dt.ToString("dd"); //it contains Day-> 03
```